# Make a gem generation run a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've made a gem which uses the rails generators.

It creates certain files including a database migration.

Is there any way of running the 'rake db:migrate' task automatically? After the user has ran the install.

Or is there a way of creating an 'ask' in the form of a 'Run db:migrate' y/n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there most certainly is. You will just want to include that line of code in the install method of said generator. (In below example MyEngine and myengine represent the name of your engine)

```
class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
    def install
        rake 'db:migrate'
    end
end
```

However, you need to do more in your install generator than just running rake db:migrate. The point of the generator is to make life easier for you when you install this bad boy.
 There are required tasks will want to perfrom first in order to properly install your engine into an app. First run bundle install, secondly mount your engine, thirdly install your migrations, and then lastly you will want to run rake db:migrate. After all is said and done, your engine's install generator will end up looking a bit more like this:

```
class InstallGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
    def install
        run 'bundle install'
        route "mount MyEngine::Engine => '/myengine'
        rake 'myengine:install:migrations'
        rake 'db:migrate'
    end
end
```

Comment: I love generators. In my engines I have generator tasks that will update my server if something goes wrong, lots of stuff. Play around with it, because with the right syntax a generator can do a lot of the same things you do in console or terminal. Good luck!